# Comparing data between website and Excel data

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am comparing a text box value and the value in excel sheet by using assert() (TestNG) 
the problem i am facing is even though the value in excel and website text box is same it is showing error - java.lang.AssertionError: expected [0.02] but found [0.0200]

[image]

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBlackCost1" class="textboxnew" type="text"
 style="width:50px;text-align: right" onblur="AllowNumber(this,this.value);
 CallonBlur(this.value,'spn_Black_1');
 Calculate_BlackChargeableRate(this.value,1,'cost');" maxlength="12" value="0.0200"
 name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBlackCost1">
```

**Selenium Code:**

```
public static void CompareStringTextByID(String xlpath,String sheetName,int rownum,int cellnum,String LocationName,String WebelementID)
{
    WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.id(WebelementID));
    String Content = TxtBoxContent.getAttribute("value");
    String ExcelData = Generic.getXlCellValue(xlpath, sheetName, rownum, cellnum);
    Assert.assertEquals(Content, ""+ExcelData);
    Reporter.log(LocationName+" Data Verification -- PASS",true);
}
```

Comment: The error displays both the string are different can you post a sample string

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings, not numbers.  "0.2" is not the same as "0.200".

Try converting them to Decimals before comparing them.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String decimal = df.format(someString);
```

Ideally, create `BigDecimal` objects and compare those.

Comment: how to convert text box string value to decimal number

Comment: @Santhosh.S ``Double.parseDouble(string);

Comment: BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(someString);

Answer (score -1):

Alter the format in the spreadsheet to match the format from your test. Or the other way around if I have read wrong. They both need to be to 2 decimal places. At least that is what I think it is.

Answer (score -2):

If you are going to compare to integer please convert the string to integer before comparing this will help you reduce the confusion
to convert the sting to Double please use

```
double aDouble = Double.parseDouble("0.02");
```

Comment: a decimal value to parse as an integer? Please rethink your example

Comment: Please understand his issue , his real issue is he is try to compare two number as string ,which is bad thing to do . i just pointed out he should do a conversion before the compare .anyway i have updated it.